# function callback to reload a jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

im new to jquery/javascript and im trying to make a function callback to reload a jquery plugin. what would be the appropriate way to do that?

```
$(function() {

    var newHash      = "",
    $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
    $el;

    $("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    });

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function(){
        newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1); 
        if (newHash) {
            $mainContent
            .find("#guts")
            .fadeOut(200, function() {
                $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function() {
                    $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
                        /*rebind plugin*/
                    });
                    $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                    $("nav a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("current");
                });
            });
        };
    });    

    $(window).trigger('hashchange');
});
```

Comment: why do you want to reload it?  and what plugin?  some example code can help your cause

Comment: what triggers the callback? when do you want to reload the plugin?

Comment: That code does not appear to have anything at all to do with reloading a jQuery plugin.

Comment: added my code, basicly all my plugins go broke cause of i'm dynamically loading html so i need to reload them somehow..they need to be reloaded after new page is done loading

Comment: When you say, "reload a plugin", people think you mean, "reload the plugin JavaScript code from the server", which really doesn't make a lot of sense. Do you mean, "**reapply** a plugin"?

Comment: yes i mean reapply/re-bind a plugin

Comment: OK then why don't you just do it in the "load()" handler?

Comment: how?? im new to javascript, sorry:)

Comment: wow i finally fixed it myself..pffft! thnx for the effort anyways

Answer (score 0):

I used this plugin before and the way i did was I added my code in the load function

```
if (newHash) {
        $mainContent
            .find("#guts")
            .fadeOut(200, function() {
                $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function() {
                    /* load in javascript you want to apply to the new content being loaded */
                    $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
                    /*rebind plugin*/   
                    });
                    $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                    $("nav a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("current");
                });
            });


    }
```

Also, if you use CSS-Tricks method then what ever jquery plugins applied from the page being loaded should already be executed.

like in the example provided from css-tricks

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script jquery.js file here>
    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
         // the stuff here will loaded to the page retrieving it already spiced up by jquery from the script in the head
```